# Printing specific columns as a percentage

Tags: pandas, dataframe, format, percentage

I have multi index dataframe and I want to convert two columns' value into percentage values.

```
                             Capacity\nMWh  Day-Ahead\nMWh  Intraday\nMWh  UEVM\nMWh  ...  Cost Per. MW\n(with Imp.)\n$/MWh  Cost Per. MW\n(w/o Imp.)\n$/MWh  Intraday\nMape  Day-Ahead\nMape
Power Plants Date                                                                     ...
powerplant1  2020 January              3.6          446.40         492.70     482.50  ...                              0.05                             0.32            0.04             0.10
             2020 February             0.0            0.00           0.00       0.00  ...                              0.00                             0.00            0.00             0.00
             2020 March                0.0            0.00           0.00       0.00  ...                              0.00                             0.00            0.00             0.00
             2020 April                0.0            0.00           0.00       0.00  ...                              0.00                             0.00            0.00             0.00
```

```
I used apply('{:0%}'.format):

nested_df[['Intraday\nMape', 'Day-Ahead\nMape']] = \
            nested_df[['Intraday\nMape', 'Day-Ahead\nMape']].apply('{:.0%}'.format)
```

But I got this error:

```
TypeError: ('unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__', 'occurred at index Intraday\nMape')
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
nested_df[['Intraday\nMape', 'Day-Ahead\nMape']] = \
        nested_df[['Intraday\nMape', 'Day-Ahead\nMape']].applymap('{:.0%}'.format)
```

Comment: so glad i have you, thank you again and again and again :))